# Form input elements are messing with URL of react page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

**ContactData.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from '../../../components/UI/Button/Button';
import classes from './ContactData.module.css'
class ContactData extends Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        age: '',
        address: {
            street: '',
            postalCode: ''
        }
    }

    orderHandler = () => {
        console.log(this.props.ingredients)
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.ingredients);
        return (
            <div className={classes.ContactData}>
                <h4>Enter Your Contact Data</h4>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Mail" />
                    <input type="text" name="street" placeholder="Street" />
                    <input type="text" name="postal" placeholder="Postal Code" />
                    <Button btnType="Success" clicked={this.orderHandler}>ORDER</Button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactData;
```

**CheckOut.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
import CheckoutSum from '../../components/Checkout/Checkout'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ContactData from '../../container/Checkout/ContactData/ContactData'
class Checkout extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ingredients: {
            salad: 1,
            meat: 1,
            cheese: 1,
            bacon: 1
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const query = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
        const ingredients = {};
        for (let param of query.entries()) {
            ingredients[param[0]] = parseInt(param[1]);
        }
        // console.log(ingredients);
        this.setState({ ingredients: ingredients });

    }

    cancelHandle = () => {
        this.props.history.goBack();
    }

    continueHandle = () => {
        this.props.history.replace('/checkout/contact-data');
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        console.log(this.state.ingredients)
        return (
            <div>
                <CheckoutSum
                    cancel={this.cancelHandle}
                    continue={this.continueHandle}
                    ingredients={this.state.ingredients}
                />
                <Route
                    path={this.props.match.path + '/contact-data'}
                    exact
                    render={() => (<ContactData ingredients={this.state.ingredients} />)} />
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Checkout;
```

Problem is when I hit Order button in CotanctData component the page reloads and for some reason my URL changes to  this  http://localhost:3000/checkout/contact-data?name=&email=&street=&postal= and then  Checkout component renders again and for some reason componentDidMount fires twice. At last I was expecting the printing of ingredients object.

Also, I'm using search query in URL to change the state of checkout component

Full Project At-https://github.com/aniket-hue/Burger-App-React/tree/Routes

Please bear with me if you don't like the question I didn't know how to frame the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either:

- Call `e.preventDefult()` on the `<form>`'s submit event.
- OR, add `<button type="button">` to your button to make it not `submit` your form.

Comment: I made a custom Button and first solution is working flawlessly. But why my URL is changing even if I don't use e.preventDefault();

Comment: Because you are using a `<form>` and you have not specified a `methond` attribute -- so it defaults to `GET`. When you click a button that is not of `type="button"` in a form, you will `submit` the form. Submitting the form looks like navigating to the page with the form data in your query-string because you have also not added an `action` to go somewhere else. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3 and https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `preventDefault` to your `orderHandler` method, beacause if button in form has no type, the type is automaticlly `submit`, so on every click your submitting a form. Also can you add `type="button"` to your `button` inside form.

```
orderHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.props.ingredients);
}
```

Comment: Solution is working flawlessly. But why my URL is changing even if I don't use  e.preventDefault().

Comment: A preventDefault is called on the event when submitting the form to prevent a browser reload/refresh. On `get` form submit without preventDefault you're pass form data as query to url. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: Okay this is make sense. Thanks for helping me out.